# Generate JSON using groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I am trying to produce the following JSON structure in Groovy but not getting the output I desire.

```
{
    "settings": [
        {
            "location": "remote",
            "stance": "cold"
        },
        {
            "spareParts": {
                "id": "123" {
                "info": "In stock"
             }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Looks you have changed a lot in the question and also removed other question. At least is the above thing final desired output?

Comment: By the way, above is not valid json.

Comment: So what have you tried and what errors do you get?  If you don't the the desired output please show us what you get, so we can improve on that.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the JSON which is in the question at the moment is invalid. :) Second, since Groovy has great support for this, it doesn't need to be ugly. :)

You can go with closures, maps or combined, see this example: https://github.com/jonatan-ivanov/groovy-training/blob/master/examples/050_JsonBuilder.groovy

Here is an example for your (I think) JSON using maps:

```
builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(
    settings: [
        [
            location: 'remote',
            stance: 'cold'
        ],
        [
            spareparts: [
                id: '123',
                info: 'In stock'
            ]
        ]
    ]
)

println builder.toPrettyString()
```

And here is its output:

```
{
    "settings": [
        {
            "location": "remote",
            "stance": "cold"
        },
        {
            "spareparts": {
                "id": "123",
                "info": "In stock"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a combination of maps and lists for this. Consider the easier case:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def map = [:]
def map1 = [:]

map1['location'] = 'remote'
def list = []
list << ['id' : '123', 'info' : 'In stock']
map1['spareParts'] = list
map['settings'] = [map1]

def jsonBuilder = new JsonBuilder(map)
println jsonBuilder.toPrettyString()
```

and then the more complex case (this should be refactored):

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def map = [:]

def map1 = [:]
map1['location'] = 'remote'
def list1 = []
list1 << ['id' : '123', 'info' : 'In stock']
map1['spareParts'] = list1
map['settings'] = map1

def map2 = [:]
map2['location'] = 'local'
def list2 = []
list2 << ['id' : '505', 'info' : 'none']
map2['spareParts'] = list2

map['settings'] = [map1, map2]

def jsonBuilder = new JsonBuilder(map)
println jsonBuilder.toPrettyString()
```

Comment: re: refactoring. That is a different question for which you should make an attempt and illustrate what you tried. If the current post helps answer your original question, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer.

Comment: this just doesn't look as fun as the other answer.